# What policies are used to prevent segregation in education today?

Tags: education, minorities

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desegregation_busing), desegregation busing is:

> Desegregation busing in the United States (also known as simply busing) is the practice of assigning and transporting students to schools so as to redress prior racial segregation of schools, or to overcome the effects of residential segregation on local school demographics.

In [an article on presidential hopeful Joe Biden's opposition to busing](https://edition.cnn.com/2019/04/11/politics/joe-biden-busing-letters-2020/index.html) at the time, they write:

> It was more than four decades ago as a battle raged across the country -- and in Congress -- over sending white students to majority-black schools and black students to majority-white schools often far away from their own neighborhoods.

---

What policies are used to prevent segregation in education today? One example that I can think of, in addition to busing, is setting racial quotas (e.g. forcing that schools have at least a certain % of people from racial minorities), though I'm not sure if that's used in any country right now.

I know this might seem broad, but most of the things I have found relate to the United States and date back to the previous millennium. Please note that I'm asking for current examples. Please include a detailed description of the desegregation policy in your answer.

Comment: Short answer: [very little](https://www.nbcnews.com/think/opinion/investigating-school-segregation-2018-nikole-hannah-jones-podcast-transcript-ncna896116). I'm at a loss as to how to summarize the whole thing without spending an hour or two going through transcript or re-listening to it again and raising the salient bits, but do read the transcript or listen to the podcast, as it definitely answers your question IMHO.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy that's just about American schools, right? I'm (more) interested in other countries given how Biden seems to be blamed for opposing 'busing'. I know the same thing happens in other countries (e.g. in [The Netherlands](https://www.nrc.nl/nieuws/2018/12/14/soort-zoekt-soort-ook-in-schoolkeuze-a3060781)) but that article also says there's less school segregation in other countries (first line of point 3), I'm curious why (what policies they use, if any, to prevent school segregation).

Comment: If memory serves me well the gist of the problem described in the podcast I linked to was that schools were currently segregated in large part because whites basically flee areas that minorities settle into and/or send their kids to private schools that minorities can't afford. Intuitively something similar occurs in Europe, but it's less visible because there's less urban sprawl.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92982/discussion-between-denis-de-bernardy-and-jjj).